# Extract elements from List of List in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to solve the HackerRank excercise "Non-Divisible Subset"
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/non-divisible-subset/

**Excercise track**
*The exercise track is about creating a program that will take in a list of integers and a number 'k', and will output the count of the maximum number of integers in the list that are not divisible by 'k' and are non-repeating.*

My problem is that results differs from Expected output.
Can you detect any problems in my code? Probably it's a logic error but I'm stuck. Please help me.

With input `k=9` and input `list = 422346306, 940894801, 696810740, 862741861, 85835055, 313720373`,
output should be `5` but my code get `6`.

```
public static int nonDivisibleSubset(int k, List<int> s)
    {
        var x = GetPerm(s);


        var y = x.Where(x => x.Value % k != 0).Select(x=>x.Key).ToList();
        var a = y.SelectMany(x => x).ToHashSet();

        return a.Count();

    }

    static Dictionary<List<int>,int> GetPerm (List<int> list)
    {
        Dictionary<List<int>,int> perm = new Dictionary<List<int>, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < list.Count; j++)
            {
                List<int> sumCouple = new List<int>();
                sumCouple.Add(list[i]);
                sumCouple.Add(list[j]);
                perm.Add(sumCouple, sumCouple.Sum());
            }

        }
        return perm;
    }
```

Comment: Questions should include all information needed to answer them. Links can go dead. Please cite the relevant parts of the assignment.

Comment: Hackerrank also needs sign in, ... so the link will be useless to many users.

Comment: excercise track added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see the actual problem is quite different:

> Given a set of distinct integers, print the size of a maximal subset of  where the sum of any  numbers in  is not evenly divisible by `k`.

If we have a look at the example:

```
list = {422346306, 940894801, 696810740, 862741861, 85835055, 313720373} 
k = 9
```

we can't take *all 6 numbers* since `940894801 + 313720373` is *evenly divisible* by `k = 9`. The required subset is all but last item: `{422346306, 940894801, 696810740, 862741861, 85835055}`

And the solution will be different as well:

```
public static int nonDivisibleSubset(int k, List<int> s)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> remainders = s
        .GroupBy(item => item % k)
        .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
        
    int result = 0;
    
    foreach (var pair in remainders) {
        if (pair.Key == 0 || pair.Key % (k / 2) == 0 && k % 2 == 0)
            result += 1;
        else if (!remainders.TryGetValue(k - pair.Key, out int count))
            result += pair.Value;
        else if (count < pair.Value)
            result += pair.Value;
        else if (count == pair.Value && pair.Key < k - pair.Key)
            result += pair.Value;
    }   
    
    return result;  
}
```

The idea is to group all the numbers by their remainder when devided by `k`. Then we do the follow:

- if remainder is `0` or `k / 2` (for even `k`) we can take just one such number into the subset
- if remainder is `x` we can add to subset either all such numbers or all the numbers which have remainder `k - x`.

Time complexity: `O(n)`
Space complexity: `O(n)`

Comment: I have missed the correct logic probably due to the wrong reading. Sorry.

Comment: @Diego: We are human beings and time to time we all misread.

Answer (score -1):

Not an answer to the question - but there is at least one problem with your code - `List`'s can't be used as a key for dictionary as is, because it does not override `Equals`/`GetHashCode`, so it will perform reference comparison. You can provide a custom equality comparer:

```cs
class PairListEqComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<int>>
{
    public static PairListEqComparer Instance { get; } = new PairListEqComparer();

    public bool Equals(List<int> x, List<int> y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.Count != 2 || y.Count != 2) return false; // or throw

        return x[0] == y[0] && x[1] == y[1];
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<int> obj) => HashCode.Combine(obj.Max(), obj.Min(), obj.Count);
}
```

And usage:

```cs
Dictionary<List<int>,int> perm = new Dictionary<List<int>, int>(PairListEqComparer.Instance);
```

Or consider using ordered value tuples (compiler will generate the needed methods). From that you can think about optimizations and better algorithm.

As for solution itself - valid brute-force approach would be to generate all permutations of all sizes, i.e. from 1 to `s.Count` and find the longest one which satisfies the condition (though I doubt that it will be efficient enough for hackerrank)

Comment: it will perform reference comparison, so that causes my output different! Damn, I'm newbie in C#, studying it since only one year. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Diego note that this will not fix your issue which is caused by the flaw in the logic -  consider 1,2,3 and k = 4, 1+3 will be filtered out but 1+2 and 2+ 3 will not, so your code will still return a wrong answer of 3 elements.

Comment: I have just changed List with tuple but the problem persists indeed. So it's a logic flaw, for me the worst problem... sigh!